# How to override custom module admin controller in Prestashop 1.6?

Tags: overriding, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have a smartblog module in Prestashop 1.6 and I need to override /modules/smartblog/controllers/admin/AdminBlogPostController.php controller. How can I do it?

I've updated the file, added needed code and updated the name:

```
class AdminBlogPostControllerOverride extends AdminBlogPostController
```

I tried these ways but they didn't work for me:

1. I put the file into /override/modules/smartblog/controllers/admin/AdminBlogPostController.php
2. I put the file into /override/controllers/AdminBlogPostController.php
3. I put the file into /modules/smartblog/override/controllers/admin/AdminBlogPostController.php

But nothing changed. Can anyone help me to find a mistake in my code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly you'd like to do? There are number of "action" Hooks which are very helpful when it comes to overriding BO

Answer (score 0):

As I know, you can't override module controllers by default in the Prestashop (1.6).

What you can do:

1. This module is not a core module, so you can edit it directly
2. Follow this tutorial : [override module controller in PS 1.6](http://nemops.com/overriding-modules-controllers-in-prestashop-1-6/#.WC-agSSS-YA) and then you can do it
3. Generate new module with custom `AdminController` and in the header or dispatcher hooks (in your module), you can redirect the page to your custom page

Answer (score 0):

Just put this file into:

```
/modules/smartblog/controllers/admin/AdminBlogPostControllerverride.php
```

and then create a new tab from Administrator -> Menues.